# nodejs express not to intercept messages for a folder with static content

Tags: node.js, express

I've a node, express system installed working on a host.

All requests are going through in the `app.get('/path'...` format

however in the domain I've html folder with static content that I want to serve

`http://domain.com/html/attendee`

`http://domain.com/html/sponsors`

and don't want node/express to intercept these requests and let them go through directly, not even serve through nodejs, otherwise relative linking problem.

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it that way.  node doesn't serve ANY content by default - it is not like some other web servers in that regard.

Instead, you specifically configure express to serve content from certain paths directly from the file system by inserting the right middleware commands early in the middleware stack.

For example, in one of my node apps, I use this middleware:

```
// static routes that get no further processing
app.use('/img', express.static(__dirname + '/img'));
app.use('/lib', express.static(__dirname + '/lib'));
```

This tells express that any content that starts with `"/img"` should be served directly from the `appDirectory + "/img"` directory.  Same for elements in `"/lib"`.  One nice thing about this is that the paths you expose to the outside world do not have to be the same as the paths you use on your server and, in fact, by changing a few characters in your code, you can easily map to different directory.